# PulseAudio: digital profiles/ports no longer appear in pavucontrol

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, profile

Until recently I could use pavucontrol to select a device's digital profile (in the configuration tab) or port (in the "output devices" tab). That latter tab also allowed me to indicate what formats a device was capable to handle beyond PCM.

These possibilities have disappeared, I can't exactly say when so I can't link it to something I may have (un)installed but I do know that I haven't updated PulseAudio (v16.1) nor pavucontrol (v5.0). Last changes I can remember making to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` was disabling Jack functionality as well as Bluetooth support.
EDIT: Upgrading to PA 16.99.1 or downgrading to 13.99.1 didn't change anything so we must be dealing with something external OR a configuration change.

Does PulseAudio need to have specific modules loaded in order to support digital device profiles/ports, and if so, which?

Comment: Perhaps `pipewire` was installed. It takes over some of pulseaudio.

Comment: Could have been, but no, alas, no pipewire on my machine. (I might try building it myself if this profile issue ever becomes a problem, though!)

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

I upgraded ALSA from 1.1.6 to 1.2.9 (1.2.7 for the plugins). Downgrading that restored access to the digital profiles, including to the HDMI output of by built-in Intel sound subsystem.

Issue isn't solved completely though, but basically becomes "what's wrong with my ALSA 1.2.x build" ...

EDIT: well, that was stupid. Turns out the `${prefix}/share/alsa` library has been reorganised, the `ucm` subdir renamed to `pcm` and the entire `topology` subdir disappeared. Normally I catch such things when looking for files that go missing during upgrades but in this case I didn't and wasn't thus alerted to the fact I simply needed to update my `alsa.conf` file...

Once that was done I had my digital (HDMI and IEC958) profiles back, yay!

(Sorry for thinking out loud, but maybe this will be of help to someone else doing their own upgrading.)

Comment: FYI with ALSA 1.2.10 and pipewire on Fedora 38 I can see these. In pavucontrol -> Configuration -> Built-in Audio -> Profile, I can see all the HDMI etc. profiles. But I don't see these settings accessible through KDE volume controls. So one possible option except for a bug might be that these are not visible until something is connected to these outputs. Because they all show as `Unavailable`. Too lazy to try connecting HDMI now though.

Comment: I do see them (in the `Audio Hardware Setup` panel) - I use the VLC phonon backend. Too lazy myself to check if the GStreamer backend is different in this.

Comment: Another, and totally unexpected bonus: PA no longer crashes when loading the bluetooth discovery module. That was a very weird crash, a SEGV somewhere in libc under a dlopen call, apparently due to some non-initialised structure provided through ALSA.